# xe.com currency conversion api

Tags: payment-gateway

i have a payment gateway in my website and i showcase the products with their prices in USD. But when users select a product to purchase, i need to convert the USD amount to INR as my payment gateway is allowing only Indian (INR) rates for transactions.

Hence i need a live currency conversion code in php, that i can use prior to the purchase of the product. I have heard about many currency conversion scripts in php, but is there a code for xe.com currency conversion ?

Please help... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the API that they publish is either a HTML widget or the [datafeed](http://www.xe.com/dfs/product.php). The latter comes in XML, html, and CSV so you should be able to access the them quite easily in PHP.

Comment: Can anyone give the link or demo code of the latter (datafeed) ?

Comment: Thanks, but iam satisfied with the google currency translator. http://phpdaily.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/usd-to-inr-conversion/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of api's available on google, but they have some limitations for use like no of api's/month, daily update for only once etc. If you want to use its paid version. It will be fine.